# C# How to Update/Change the specific letter/number of a string in database

Tags: c#, winforms

I ask these question coz i really don't know how i'm gonna do that and is it possible to do that?
What i want is to update/change here for example STA-100418-100 in database values, update/change the 100 based on the user input, like 50 it will be STA-100418-50.

Here's the provided image to be more precise
[image]
As you can see on the image, there's a red line, if user update the quantity as 60, In Codeitem STA-100418-100 should be STA-100418-60
I really have no idea on how to do that. I hope someone would be able to help me

here's my code for updating the quantity

```
private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
    {
        using (var selects = new SqlCommand("Update Product_Details set quantity = quantity - @Quantity where ProductID= @ProductID", con))
        {
            selects.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_productid.Text;
            selects.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Quantity;
            selects.ExecuteNonQuery();                          
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code to get that format in codeitems

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy");
string shortdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("-MMddy-");
private void Quantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Code.Text = Supplier.Text.Substring(0, 3) + shortdate + Quantity.Text;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like `CodeItem` should be dynamically constructed from data in other fields, not a literal string of its own.  Storing the same information (in this case the value "60") in multiple places is often a recipe for problems.

Comment: Agreed with @David. You should be able to either define a view on your `Product_Details` table that adds a `CodeItem` column constructed from the underlying data, or add a computed column directly to the table itself. Is there any reason why you don't want to go that route? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sql server, to get this STA-100418-100 i use string concatination + datetime and 100 is based on the user inputs

Answer (score 0):

User will input everytime in the Quantity textbox, the textchanged event of Quantity will be hit and you will get new value everytime with the same date but with different quantity. So you can use the Code.Text to update the CodeDateTime value or you can use a global variable instead of Code.Text and use it to update the column.

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy");
string shortdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("-MMddy-");
private void Quantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Code.Text = Supplier.Text.Substring(0, 3) + shortdate + Quantity.Text;
}

        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var selects = new SqlCommand("Update Product_Details set quantity = quantity - @Quantity, CodeItem = @Code where ProductID= @ProductID", con))
            {
                selects.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_productid.Text;
                selects.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Quantity;
                selects.Parameters.Add("@Code", Code.Text);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to update SQL-Server

```
public static DataTable GetSqlTable(string sqlSelect)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            return table;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(table);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();

        return table;
    }

public static void GetSqlNonQuery(string sqlSelect)
    {
        string newObject = string.Empty;
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        connection.Open();

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string x = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Here's how to use it

```
DataTable dt = GetSqlTable("select Quantity from product where CodeItem = 'STA-100418-100'");
string strQuantity = dt.Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();
GetSqlNonQuery(string.Format("UPDATE product SET CodeItem = '{0}' WHERE  = 'STA-100418-100'", strQuantity));
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it you need MSSQL String Functions

```
SELECT rtrim(left(Codeitem,charindex('-', Codeitem))) + ltrim(str(Quantity)) FROM ...
```

[For detailed information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code and links. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using MySql, Substring the code item and then concatenate the quantity.

```
UPDATE Product_Details SET quantity = @quantity,CodeIem = CONCAT(SUBSTR(@code,1,11),@quantity) WHERE ProductID= @ProductID
```